# Why is the file size in bytes not equal to the summed byte size of every line?

Tags: c#, parsing, text, progress-bar

I try to create a progress bar that displays the progress of a parser reading a text file.

To do that, I read the bytes of the file using `fileSize = FileInfo(file).Length` and in every iteration, I sum up the bytes of the current line using

`sum += reader.CurrentEncoding.GetByteCount(currentLine)`

I assumed that when I'm finished reading the whole file, `sum` should be equal to `fileSize`.

But, that's not the case. `sum` is always several thousand bytes lower than `fileSize`. Why is this? How can I correctly create a progress that displays how many of the file I have already parsed?

Comment: Is the number of missing bytes equal to (or double of) the number of lines in your file, by any chance?

Comment: Maybe the reader.CurrectEncoding.GetByteCount does not count carriage return / line feedback characters?

Comment: are you counting the bytes on the newline characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be several reasons for that, most likely it's due to the encoding. I'm not talking about things like UTF-8 encoding or similar ones, but line endings too.

For example, a text file might contain two lines with two words:

```
Hello
World
```

Counting just the bytes of each line, you'd end up with 10 bytes (5 characters each). However, depending on the file encoding, it will have a line ending marked by `\r`, `\r\n` or `\n`, which is not contained in the length of the line.

Depending on your file size you could either read the whole file into a `String[]` or instead use the stream's current position as a progress indicator.

Answer (score 8):

Because `ReadLine()` will remove the Line endings. Usually CR+LF but unfortunately there are other conventions (just LF) for Text files.

I suppose you can find out what the LineFeed is in your data and just add the lenght, no need to bother with Encoding :

```
sum += reader.CurrentEncoding.GetByteCount(currentLine) + 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Does that `currentLine` include the newline chars at the end? What if you do

```
sum += reader.CurrentEncoding.GetByteCount(currentLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: This won't work in all cases, because `Environment.NewLine` might contain `\r\n` or simply `\n`. However this doesn't mean the file uses the same encoding (it might have been created on a Unix system for example).

Answer (score 0):

This is because every file in the file system also has a header with meta data such as permissions, timestamps etc. Also you are not accounting for special characters such as line feeds, line endings, end of file. Don't worry about it, just use your sum of lines if you want to be precise with your progress bar or the FileInfo if not really.

Comment: The meta data does not count in the filesize, it's stored separately. You are right about end-of-line and end-of-file.